# Very small numbers

Tags: java

I am writing a Mandelbrot viewer. Everything works except when you get to a very high zoom the image starts to pixilate about at about zoom 10^(-14). I am guessing because i run out of memory in my double vars. What can i use that will allow me to use very small numbers?

I need to use the java.lang.Math class and i dont think that supports bigdecimal

Comment: What do you mean by you "need" to use java.lang.Math...is this homework?  If so you should tag it as such.

Comment: its not homework i need to use various methods in the Math class for calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing about how you're doing it, but if you can do your calculations in log-space you can deal with tiny numbers much better (since they become large negative numbers).

Comment: I am already doing that however that method lacks the precision i require.

Comment: Then BigDecimal is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need arbitrary precision, your best option is probably [`BigDecimal`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

If you're concerned with efficiency, I suspect you would be better off trying to scale your values and keep them in the neighborhood of 1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The following discussion seems quite informative: [High-Performance Arbitrary precision numerical calculations in Java (Mandelbrot Set!)](http://groups.google.com/group/javaposse/browse_thread/thread/6036033dbcf19ed7/58c6805e6f8861bd?hide_quotes=no&pli=1).

Answer (score 1):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java's `BigDecimal`.

Comment: How would that help? He's not dealing with integers.

Comment: I failed to see the minus sign. (sigh). Updated.